# Http Response Contains MIME stream.. which has binary Images seperated by Boundary String.. need to get those Images and save using c#

Tags: c#, email, httpresponse, mime

when i make a HTTP request to the server it responses with the MIME Response Stream which has two or more images in it as Binary data which are separated by Boundary String 
Now i need to extract those images only and save them individually into database

Stream Looks like this...

Header has

```
RETS-Version: RETS/1.0

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-type: multipart/parallel;

boundary="simple boundary"
```

**Http ResoinseStream Has**

--simple boundary

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-ID: 123456

Object-ID: 1

<binary data>(Image1)
```

--simple boundary

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-ID: 123457

Object-ID: 1

<binary data>(Image2)
```

--simple boundary --

I need to extract image1 and image2 and save those in database as binary image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library, you can do this really easily:

```
static MimeEntity ParseHttpWebResponse (HttpWebResponse response)
{
    var contentType = ContentType.Parse (response.ContentType);

    return MimeEntity.Parse (contentType, response.GetResponseStream ());
}

static void SaveAllImages (HttpWebResponse response)
{
    var entity = ParseHttpWebResponse (response);
    var multipart = entity as Multipart;

    if (multipart != null) {
        foreach (var image in multipart.OfType<MimePart> ()) {
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream ()) {
                image.ContentObject.DecodeTo (memory);

                var blob = memory.ToArray ();

                // save it to your database
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will Work on it and let u know